# Equivalence of metrics

Tags: general-topology

I've got problem with following:
$\phi : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-decreasing, concave function. Such that $\phi (0) =0$, and $\phi (u) >0$ for $u>0$. Prove that if $\phi$ is continuous at $0$ then $\mathcal{T} (d_{\phi}))=\mathcal{T} (d))$, where $d$ is a metric on $X$ and $d_{\phi}(x,y) = \phi (d(x,y))$.

I can prove that $d_\phi$ is metric on $X$. I've stucked with above problem.

Comment: What is not clear? I know my English is very bad, but I'm working on it :)

Comment: Could you tell us what $X$ is?

Comment: I meant, the statement of the problem is clear, but you say you got problem on this exercise. My question what: which king of problems? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The statement of the problem is not clear. Or rather, it is clearly wrong, if the required conclusion $(X,d_{\phi})=(X,d)$ is read as $X=X$ (obviosly true) and $d_{\phi}=d$ (obviously false). My guess: The requirement is to show that $d_\phi$ and $d$ are *equivalent* metrics.

Comment: $X$ is a set. I know that i have to prove that $(X,d_\phi) \subset (X,d)$ and $(X,d) \subset (X,d_\phi)$, i.e. every open set in $(X,d_\phi)$ is open in $(X,d)$.
@Harald Hanche-Olsen, yes, you're right, sorry for that :)

Comment: And my guess is confirmed, thanks! What a terrible abuse of the equality and inclusions signs. But all is clear now.

Comment: I suggest you change the problem title to the more accurate “Equivalence of metrics”.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by proving: For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ so that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d_\phi(x,y)<\epsilon$ – and also $d_\phi(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. (For your sanity's sake, concentrate on one of these at a time.)

These are not *necessary* requirements for the metrics to be queivalent, but they are *sufficient*. And in this case, you can prove them without too much hazzle, I hope.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) 
For first we can take $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \sup \{x: \phi (x) < \epsilon \} $ ($\delta >0$ because $\phi$ i continuous at $0$). Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, that should work. (Did I really write queivalent? Well, it's such a cute misprint I'll leave it as is.)